# Unir ciertas hojas de calculo Excel con encabezado R

Tags: r

Tengo un libro de Excel con 25 hojas de calculo
(Inicio,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12  1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, 5D, 6D, 7D, 8D, 9D, 10D, 11D, 12D)

Quiero unir solo 12 hojas de calculo
(1D, 2D, 3D, 4D, 5D, 6D, 7D, 8D, 9D, 10D, 11D, 12D)

-Cada hoja tiene el mismo número de columnas y los mismos nombres de variables
-Cada hoja tiene un número diferente de fila; es decir, unas tienen más filas que otras
-La información que deseo unir empieza desde la fila 3 en adelante

¿cómo uno estas 12 hojas en un solo dataframe?
¿cómo renombro las variables?

Dejo el archivo excel para que me ayuden por favor, gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido Estadistica Zona5 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.